# how to runtime image and get new image use handler

Tags: android, handler, android-imageview, runnable

How i can runtime and get new image, i newbie on android, i am using eclipse for this project, i don't know how to make it this runnable, can somebody tell me how to get it ?

full code Main Activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

EditText inputUrl;
OnClickListener getImageBtnOnClick = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Editable ed = inputUrl.getText();
        Drawable image = ImageOperations(context,ed.toString(),"image.jpg");
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imgView.setImageDrawable(image);
        Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
                 public void run() { 
                 } 
            }, 10000);     

    }
};
```

========================================================================================

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputUrl = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1));
    inputUrl.setSingleLine();
    inputUrl.setTextSize(11);
    Button getImageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    getImageButton.setOnClickListener(getImageBtnOnClick);
}
private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
        return d;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    URL url = new URL(address);
    Object content = url.getContent();
    return content;
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="Button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_search" />
```

Comment: well what is the error

Comment: on this code "imgView.setImageResource(R.id.imageView1);"

Comment: that does not tell me what the error is that you are seeing

Comment: only one problem, i want to runnable image, and i use runnable but i always have error if i given runnable code, can you resolve the runnable and handler ?

Comment: so like I said WHAT DOES THE ERROR SAY!!

Comment: change modifier of "imgView to final"

Comment: the error explains itself, the imageview needs to be final

Comment: i change to final but, i get error from that, and must be remove final and i get any error like this, remove "final" modifier of "imgView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is your problem

```
final ImageView imgView = new ImageView(context);
```

Comment: but i have another error on 'imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);' and must delete final ImageView imgview = new ImageView(contetxt);

Comment: you dont even need that line since you already have the imageview in your xml all you have to do is `final ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);`

Comment: so i delete "imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);" ?

Comment: i trying but no image display on activity,

Comment: your original question has been answered, you should create another question